# How to organize my first angularJS simple project?

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to create a SPA using AngularJS.
I know concepts of AngularJS, however I lack experience with planning the whole project, since I have never created a real project with it.

The template is quite simple: there is a nav header at the top (that switch either user is loggedon or not) and the content of the site.

The header has 2 views (depending if user is loggedon or not) and container has many views (photo gallery, video gallery etc...)

There may be also a simple footer, working the same way as header.

[image]

1) Should I use 1 global controler for whole site or have a headerController and containerController ?

2) Have would these 2 controllers communicate ? (ex: header controller stores the username and password of a loggedon user) ?

Maybe someone could provide a simple stub of AngularJS arhcitecture for such a website ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) use a "global" controller, controlling the top level view and scope, and others controllers can control each component that have its own behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="BodyCtrl">

<section id="navbar" data-ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <!-- ... -->
</section>

<section id="content" data-ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
    <div data-ng-controller="FirtSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="SecondSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>  
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Controllers can communicate between themselves using events, but it should be used in restricted situations. Instead, you should write some services (or factory, value, provider) to encapsulate the shared logic in your app (and shared objects). Then you can inject any  service in each controller that need it.

```
angular.module('myapp',[]) // define the myapp module

.factory('myService', ['', function(){ // define a service to share objects and methods

    var _myLogic = function(){
        // ...
        return ret;
    };

    var _myObject = {
        prop1: "my first prop value",
        prop2: "my second prop value"
    };

    return {

        myLogic: _myLogic,
        myObject: _myObject

    };
}])

.controller('BodyCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){

    $scope.myScopeMethod = myService.myLogic;

    $scope.myObject = myService.myObject;

}])

.controller('FirtSubCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){

    $scope.myScopeMethod = myService.myLogic;

    $scope.myObject = myService.myObject;

}])

;
```

Here you can notice that two controllers can share the exact (or not) object or method, injecting the shared services.

Dealing with ng-view means dealing with templates :

Here you index :

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="BodyCtrl">

        <section id="navbar" data-ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
            <!-- ... -->
        </section>

        <ng-view></ng-view>

    </body>
</html>
```

And your views :

```
<!-- template/contentIfLogged.html -->
<section id="contentIfLogged" data-ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
    <div data-ng-controller="FirtSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="SecondSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>  
</section>
```

and

```
<!-- template/contentIfNOTLogged.html -->
<section id="contentIfNOTLogged" data-ng-controller="Content2Ctrl">

    <div data-ng-controller="ThirdSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="FourthSubCtrl">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>  

</section>
```

Now, you have to configure your routes to enable the correct view, onevent or button click.

```
angular.module('myapp').config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/notlogged', 
            {templateUrl: 'template/contentIfLogged.html'}
        )
        .when('/logged', 
            {templateUrl: 'template/contentIfNOTLogged.html'}
        )
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/notlogged'})
});
```

Now, in your `<section id="nav">` element, you can add these buttons :

```
<section id="navbar" data-ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <a class="btn" href="#logged">
        Logged view
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="#notlogged">
        Not logged view
    </a>
</section>
```

and then, switch between your view clicking it.

Or, programmaticaly, in your controller (or in a service), you can switch using the $location angular service :

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'myService', function($scope, $location, myService){

    $scope.myScopeMethod = myService.myLogic;

    $scope.myObject = myService.myObject;

    var login = function(){
        $location.path('/logged');
    };
    var logout = function(){
        $location.path('/notlogged');
    };

}])
```

To you to fill the gaps to fit your application, but the base organization of your simple app is there.

Comment: Getting clearer for me.. except: where is the view for the content of the website ? (the green box in th etemplate) N

Comment: The view is provided by the `<ng-view></ng-view>` in the index.html (see the second HTML block code in my answe). This element will be replaced by the *partial* templates `template/contentIfLogged.html` and `template/contentIfNotLogged.html`. In my example, you have a big view that provide the content of the website, which is rendered either by a partial or the other.